# Trouble implementing a countdown timer in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I was playing around with JavaFx's animation Framework to build a timer that would countdown from 25 minutes.

Right now my code does countdown from 25 minutes but does not update or animate the Label every second. This is what I have tried so far:

This is the event Handler that begins the countdown when the button is clicked

```
public class CountdownActionEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

private Timer defaultTime;
private Label timer;
private Timeline animation;
private int minutes;
private int seconds;

public CountdownActionEvent(Timer timer, Label label) {
    this.defaultTime = timer;
    this.timer = label;
}

private void CountDown() {

    for (this.minutes = 25; minutes >= 0; minutes--) {
        for (this.seconds = 59; seconds >= 0; seconds--) {
            this.defaultTime.setMinutes(minutes);
            this.defaultTime.setSeconds(seconds);
            timer.setText(defaultTime.toString());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> CountDown()));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play();

}
}
```

Also This is the Timer class that is assigned to the "defaultTime" object:

```
public class Timer {

private String minutes;
private String seconds;

public Timer() {
    this.minutes = "25";
    this.seconds = "00";
}

public String getMinutes() {
    return this.minutes;
}

public String getSeconds() {
    return this.seconds;
}

public void setMinutes(int min) {
    if (min < 10) {
        this.minutes = "0" + min;
    } else {
        this.minutes = min + "";
    }
}

public void setSeconds(int sec) {
    if (sec < 10) {
        this.seconds = "0" + sec;
    } else {
        this.seconds = sec + "";
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return this.minutes + ":" + this.seconds;
}

}
```

when I run this program, the Label "timer" instantly updates to 0 upon pressing the button. I have tried to look for a possible solution but cant seem to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> CountDown()));
animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
animation.play();
```

Calls this method<sup>1</sup>:

```
private void CountDown() {

    for (this.minutes = 25; minutes >= 0; minutes--) {
        for (this.seconds = 59; seconds >= 0; seconds--) {
            this.defaultTime.setMinutes(minutes);
            this.defaultTime.setSeconds(seconds);
            timer.setText(defaultTime.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Once every second.

However, the `for` loops reset the time to `25` minutes and counts down to `0` **for each invocation of `CountDown()`**. There is no delay in this count down. Every second the timer will go from `25` to `0` as quickly as it takes your computer to execute the code. Due to the speed at which this happens, as well as the delayed-rendering JavaFX uses, you will only ever see the `Label` text go from `25:00` to `0:00`.

What you want to do is decrement the seconds by `1` each time `CountDown()` is invoked. If the seconds are at `0` then decrement the minutes by `1` and reset the seconds to `59`. Something like the following:

```
private void countDown() {
    if (seconds == 0) {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
    defaultTime.setMinutes(minutes);
    defaultTime.setSeconds(seconds);
    timer.setText(defaultTime.toString());
}
```

Don't forget to stop the animation once the countdown is complete.

---

<sup>1. Following proper Java naming conventions, the method should be named `countDown()`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing this out! Will keep note of this in the future. Appreciate the feedback